# Looking for monotonic function example that satisfies several conditions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need an example of any monotonic function that:

1) grows asymptotically to 8/3:  f(infinity)=8/3 and f(x)<=8/3 for any x,

2) f(1)=1,

3) easy to write in programming (JavaScript language)

4) pretty fast to calculate the function value

I've found a function that is OK for 1)..4). For example it could be
`f(x)=8/3 -(5/3)*(1/x)`;

However, I need 5) as well:

5) for small x (from 1 to 5) it doesn't grow so fast, but is around 2.0 for f(6). Let's say it is something like:
f(1)=1, f(2)<=1.2, f(3)<=1.4,  f(6)>1.8, f(6)<2.0.

For my example above f(2) = 1.8(3), that is too much.

I appreciate if somebody helps me with minimum changes of my function so it looks tricky and smart and 1)-5) are met.  (the less changes or the shorter function, the better).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a sigmoid function. Common examples are

$\phi(x)=0.5+\arctan(x)/\pi$, $\phi(x)=1/(1+\exp(-x))$, $\phi(x)=0.5+0.5\,x/(1+|x|))$.

They all grow from 0 to 1 and have their turning point at 0.

By translating and scaling you can adapt them to your situation, using $f(x)=c*\phi(ax+b)$. Obvious conditions are that $c=8.3$ and $a>0$.

You want the turning point to be larger than 6, i.e., $6a+b<0$, for instance by putting the turning point at 10 to 20, e.g. at 15 by demanding $15a+b=0$.

$f(1)=1$ one has to solve directly. In the first function example, this leads to the equation $a+b=\tan(\pi*(1/8.3-0.5))\approx -2.5$. With the turning point at 15, this gives $a=2.5/14\approx 0.2$ and thus $b=-2.7$.

With (a,b,c)=(0.2,-2.7,8.3) you get $f(1)\approx 1$, $f(8)\approx 2$, the turning point with value 4.15 at about x=13, $f(23)\approx 7$.

To be able to claim the homework as your own effort, I would suggest that you determine the constants in a similar fashion for the second example function, the logistic function.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more fitting as a comment but i don't yet have enough reputation to post it as such:

A straightforward solution would be to handle the small x-es with a polynomial function and then use your function for x>6 (or from wherever the polynomial and your function intersects).
I imagine polynomials would be pretty fast to calculate, and if you don't know how to interpolate, [wolfram alpha can do it for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2C1.15%7D%2C%7B3%2C1.35%7D%2C%7B6%2C2%7D%2C%7B7%2C4%7D%2C).

(this answer completely fails at looking "tricky and smart" though, and the function won't be short or simple by any means)